# Scrolling between items FlipView Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, flipview

I want to make a flipview which permit to scroll between items with the mouse scroll.
Is it possible? I also would like to know where I can find the default Flipview style.

(I'm using C#/XAML)

Thank you.

Comment: _Is it possible?_ Did you try it?

Comment: Hello, I'm curious if you ever found a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I took the default style and I modified

```
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="False"/>
```

I see the horizontal scrollviewer but I can't scroll with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the FlipView in Windows 8.1 (try upgrading the project) does this by default actually. I started a new project with a FlipView and it worked out of the box. You should upgrade the project base anyway, so try that.